# Multiple line using named ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I am attempting to plot multiple named ranges on to a chart. These named ranges (named for example `Time_Series_1`) are of the form:
`=INDIRECT(Ranges!$AJ$3)` where this argument `Ranges!$AJ$3` is for example

```
 ="'Source Data'!"&ADDRESS(N3,(Comparisons!$G$28+5))&":"&ADDRESS(N3(Comparisons!$I$28+5))
```

The code I'm attempting to use to plot the these ranges (I have started with one as any more remain to be impossible as one is not working) is:

```
Sheets("Comparisons").Select
Sheet10.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate

Set Rng = range("Time_Series_1")
Set Date_Rng = range("Time_Series_Dates_1")

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng
    .XValues = Date_Rng
End With
```

It's not working! The Chart remains blank. Completely empty. What am I not updating? What am I not activating?

Thanks

Comment: What is Sheet10?

Comment: Just the sheet number, such a reference is equivalent  to  Sheets("Comparisons"), just me being lazy. Sorry

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit in your module?

Comment: yes I do. How would that make a difference? What's your thoughts? Not being argumentative,  trying to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no way of testing your model, but try this:

```
Dim Chart_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim My_Chart As ChartObject
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Date_Rng As Range

Set Chart_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparisons")
Set My_Chart = Chart_Sheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")
Set Rng = Range("Time_Series_1")
Set Date_Rng = Range("Time_Series_Dates_1")

With My_Chart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Date_Rng
End With
```

(I am assuming that your Indirect reference works properly)

Comment: Hi RADO I get the run time error of "object does not support this property or method"?!? Weird! I don't get what's going on!

Comment: Can we use the usual ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Rng approach with named ranges? Not possible is it?

Comment: You don't need to use ActiveChart, VBA allows to manipulate the chart object directly, without activation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Date_Rng
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Rng
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dates"
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
  ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Pounds"
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
```

Comment: Possibly not the most efficient or optimal

Comment: Try my code again, it works - I just tested it successfully

Comment: It does indeed. Cheers buddy! I cant up vote yet, but have given you a tick